# ViewPager scrolls vertically

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I just want to know whether or not the `viewpaer` can be scrolled vertically. In other words, how can I make the `viewPager` when I swipe vertically not horizontally, the pager view changes? it that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 it that possible?
```

Not with the default implementation. You have to subclass `ViewPager` and implements your Gesture. From the documentation

> Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through
>   pages of data.

Comment: thank you for the answer, where did you know that? i have seaarched for such info but i did not find any

Comment: It's in the documentation. First line of the class description. *Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data.*